# Is it impossible to compute $\frac{11\sin(52)}{\sin(116)} = ? $ without knowing the exact value of $\sin(52)$ and $\sin(116)$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{11\sin(52)}{\sin(116)}  = ? $$

I wondered whether there exists such way that allows me to compute this quickly or easier. Could you share your dear thoughts with me?

**EDIT:**

Since $\sin (\pi - x ) = \sin (x)$ we have that

$$\frac{11\sin(52)}{\sin(116)}  = \frac{11\sin(52)}{\sin(26)}$$

In this case, $52$ is $2$ times of $26$. We can use double angle identity.

Comment: I did not do the calculations, but have you tried using the formulas of sine of sum?

Comment: @manooooh I haven't. Should I try?

Comment: @KM101 Then what would you recommend?

Comment: Sorry, I read the question incorrectly for a second. Do you want an approximation?

Comment: @KM101 Maybe but isnt it possible to get an integer value?

Comment: No, I just checked, it isn’t.

Comment: @KM101 Well, how can we get an approximation without knowing their exact values?

Comment: @KM101 That maybe useful in this case.

Comment: @KM101 If $\sin (116) = \sin (26)$, we can rewrite it as $\frac{11\sin(52)}{\sin(116)}  = \frac{11\sin(52)}{\sin(26)} $. Since 52 is 2 times of 26, what about using double angle identity?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the equality in your last comment in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using degrees, we have $\sin(116)=\sin (90+26)=\cos (26)$  Then
$$\frac {11\sin (52)}{\sin (116)}=\frac {11\cdot2\sin (26)\cos (26)}{\cos (26)}=22\sin (26)$$
which is simpler but not a decimal answer.  After this, you can use a Taylor series centered at $\sin(30)$ to get an approximate answer.

Comment: It was unbelieveable simpiflication, directly lead me to the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\sin(90+x) = \cos x \implies \sin (116) = \cos (26)$$

$$\implies \frac{11\sin (52)}{\cos (26)}$$

And recall $$\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$$

which yields

$$\frac{22\sin(26)\cos(26)}{\cos (26)} = 22\sin{(26)}$$

You could estimate using the expansion for $\sin x $ perhaps, which doesn’t seem too practical here.

$$\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+…$$

Using $x = \frac{13\pi}{90}$ (in radians) and evaluating the first two or three terms, you can get a decent approximation and multiply the value by $22$.

Comment: Everything seems to be clear till $22\cos(26)$. What about the rest?

Comment: Sorry, made an error. Corrected.